# Arduino MKR1000 not able to connect to AWS API Gateway

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, https, arduino, gateway

I tried modifying the basic Arduino code from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Wifi101WiFiWebClient) in order to send HTTP Requests to AWS API Gateway. While the example code from the link worked, I was not able to get a successful connection with AWS API Gateway.

I have tried a combination of things such as removing the **https://** from **server[]**, changing the port to **443** instead of **80**, removing the **/beta** from **server[]**, using **client.connectSSL** instead of **client.connect**, but none of these have worked so far.

The line:
**int err = client.connect(server, 80);**
returns me a value of 0.

There are no certificates set up with the AWS API Gateway, so I don't think it's a problem with that. Wifi works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include "arduino_secrets.h" 
///////please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab/arduino_secrets.h
char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = SECRET_PASS;    // your network password (use for WPA, or 
use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
char server[] = "https://**********.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
   ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWiFiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  int err = client.connect(server, 80);
  Serial.println(err);
  if (err) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /beta HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: https://**********.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}


void printWiFiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

(1) client.connect(fqdn, port) is expecting an FQDN for the first parameter
The example in the docs is client.connect("Arduino.cc", 80) this seems to work well in my tests.  The docs say "URL" but they mean FQDN.

(2) If you need SSL then you MUST load up your certs using the firmware updater
 first.  If you are using non-standard pins for the WiFi101 board then you MUST use wifi.setPins() to set the pins or the firmware updater will fail.  Adafruit Feather M0 1500 owners will know what I am talking about here.

Reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101ClientConnect

I hope this helps.